# Add new object to array based on list with new key and value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, push

I have a checkbox to make a selection of objects from a list. To make the selection recognizable i want to add a new keyvalue to the selected objects with the label of the selected value.

I tried the following:

```
var checkCheckboxOnOff = [{"fieldName":"Categorie__c","picklistValue":"Techniek"},{"fieldName":"Regio__c","picklistValue":"Midden"}]
```

I loop trough checkCheckboxOnOff where I select objects from a list:

```
opleidingfilter = serverList.filter(function(item) { return item[checkCheckboxOnOff[i].fieldName] == checkCheckboxOnOff[i].picklistValue});
```

While looping trough the list I add a key and value to the selected objects and push them into a filter array:

```
    opleidingfilter.forEach(function(n) {n.arrayPicklist = checkCheckboxOnOff.fieldName});
 Array.prototype.push.apply(filter,opleidingfilter[i]);
```

My problem is that when I select a an object twice I end up with both selected objects being updated with the last Key and value. My expectation is when having selected 1 object twice I end up with 2 different values.

Example:
1st selection:

```
[{"Id":"120"},{"Id":"121"}]
```

2nd Selection

```
[{"Id":"123"},{"Id":"121"}]
```

Expected:

```
[{"Id":"120","arrayPicklist":"Categorie__c"},
{"Id":"121","arrayPicklist":"Categorie__c"},{"Id":"123","arrayPicklist":"Regio__c"},
{"Id":"121","arrayPicklist":"Regio__c"}]
```

Current result

```
[{"Id":"120","arrayPicklist":"Categorie__c"},
    {"Id":"121","arrayPicklist":"Regio__c"},{"Id":"123","arrayPicklist":"Regio__c"},
    {"Id":"121","arrayPicklist":"Regio__c"}]
```

Seem to get undefined for the value in fiddle see:https://jsfiddle.net/Lcg1qca3/18/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in

```
n.arrayPicklist = checkCheckboxOnOff.fieldName
```

You're trying to access a fieldname property on an array, instead of an index in the checkCheckboxOnOff array.

Replace that line with this

```
opleidingfilter.forEach(function(n,i) {n.arrayPicklist = checkCheckboxOnOff[i].fieldName});
```

This way you have access to the index property in your iterator, and can access every item in your checkCheckboxOnOff array.